# How to use an interface here

Tags: c#

Could someone please help me with any suggestions to improvise this kind of code structure. I have a class `BlogArticle` and a page where I need to show a list of all blog articles.

```
public class BlogArticle
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

So, I wrote this one to get all the BlogArticles.

```
public class BlogArticlesSource
{
  public List<BlogArticle> GetBlogArticles() 
  {
     //code to get list of all blog articles
  }
}
```

It works fine, but there is a new requirement where there are no. of new article types that are not same but similar.

```
public class NewsArticle
{
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}

public class VlogArticle
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string TargetURL { get; set; }
}
```

But for any article type, ultimately, I need to get the respective list and show it on page.

I can inherit from a base Article class, but is there something that can be done about the "ArticleSource" classes. I do not want to go on creating "VlogArticleSource", "NewsArticleSource" and so on.....

Can I have only one such "SourceClass" and use it in all logic.

If there is any other way to improve or simplify this structure, please advise.

Comment: You need to search about **inheritance**. And also what **abstract** means. And **Factory Design Pattern** would be useful with `GetBlogArticles`. Good luck :)

Comment: What didn't you understand about how to implement an interface?  What did you try, and how did it fail to work?

Comment: You could do as @Berkay recommends and use the class `ArticleBase` as a base class for `VlogArticle` and `BlogArticle` where `ArticleBase` has the properties `Title` and `TargetUrl`

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a interface with those properties like

```
public interface IArticle
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Have the concrete type implement the interface then

```
public class BlogArticle : IArticle
{ }

public class NewsArticle : IArticle
{ }

public class VlogArticle : IArticle
{ }
```

Have your list return a `IArticle` type rather like

```
public class BlogArticlesSource
{
  public List<IArticle> GetBlogArticles() 
  {
     //code to get list of all blog articles
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ragul. Could you please explain, how to get the respective lists in your example. That was my main concern.

Answer (score 1):

From the way I read that question, you need to derive from a base class. I think you're confusing the difference between a base class and interface.

```
public class ArticlesSource
{
    public List<NewsArticle> GetNewsArticles() { ... }
    public List<VlogArticle> GetVlogArticles() { ... }
    public List<BlogArticle> GetBlogArticles() { ... }
}

public class NewsArticle : ArticlesSource
{
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}

public class VlogArticle : ArticlesSource
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string TargetURL { get; set; }
}
```

Read more about inheritance [here in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)

Derive from this base class and you can access the methods. So, you could do...

```
var vlog = new VlogArticle();
var vlogArticles = vlog.GetVlogArticles();

var news = new NewsArticle();
var newsArticles = news.GetNewsArticles();
```

Alternatively, if you want to get fancy, you could just have one `GetArticleSource<T>` using `generics`.

Comment: Could you please explain how will I be getting respective lists as output, in your example

Comment: Since your base class (`BlogArticlesSource`) already has `List<BlogArticle> GetBlogArticles`, and your other classes, `NewsArticle` and `VlogArticle` are deriving from that, you can now access any of the properties from `BlogArticlesSource`. So, you could do... `var vlog = new VlogArticle();` and call `var articles = vlog.GetBlogArticles();`

Comment: @Qwerty I reread your question, so I updated it based on the different types.